# How do I get Flow to validate Web APIs in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am using Flow static type checking in a simple React project. This works. I want to open the new multimedia web APIs. This does not.

Flow apparently does not validate types that are built into the newer browsers but not natively recognized yet, ie MediaRecorder and navigator.mediaDevices. My code does very trivial things (which work) like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
    .then(blah blah blah
```

Trying to use these results in errors like:

> Cannot call navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia because property getUserMedia is missing in undefined [1].

Similarly, attempts to allocate new MediaRecorder(stream) results in "Cannot resolve name MediaRecorder". [see Updates for answer]

Ideal solution would be "require this npm library which defines types for flow for Web Apis." Another ideal part of the solution would be "this is how you define types for things you don't own that Flow does not understand natively." I probably would even benefit from a simple "this is how you tell Flow to ignore this object", which appears to be failing me.

This is clearly a very simple problem that should be very easy to solve, but unfortunately it is very difficult to search for documentation on "Flow" because its name is so common. So common, in fact, that we can not use it as a tag here on SO. (I suspect the correct tag would be "facebook-flow" if I could create tags, which I can not. ;) )

Help? Maybe the question really should be "how can I search for Flow documentation without having Google redirect my search into hydrodynamics?"

### Updates and Learnings since posting the question

For beginners, note that that Flow comes with definitions for browser built-in WebApi functions such as MediaRecorder, but you must refer to them fully qualified: "window.MediaRecorder". Once you realize this, it seems trivially obvious; you should not be referencing objects from the global namespace. If you frequently hop languages, this is easy to forget, and this is not helped by the fact that examples at MDN and other official documentation sites frequently omit "window." Root your paths in window or navigator.

Also, for reference:

> The tag you are searching for is flowtype – trixn

Comment: The tag you are searching for is `flowtype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your code snippet to pass flow by first asserting that navigator.mediaDevices exists. The following will work:

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
}
```

If you consult the [flow definition for Navigator](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.66.0/lib/bom.js#L106), the mediaDevices property is an optional Object (`mediaDevices?: Object`)

As you stated, navigator.mediaDevices is not implemented in all browsers yet, so it makes sense for the property to be optional, as it may or may not be there depending on where the code is running. Thus, flow makes you check that mediaDevices is there before you can use it, preventing runtime errors in Safari.

One resource I would point you towards is https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/. It's where I start whenever I have a question about the built-in types.

Comment: I start with that cheat sheet as well; it is a valuable resource. It is, of course, also not in any way applicable to my question. :) The key here is understanding that the error message "property is missing in undefined" indicates that "mediaDevices" is valid, but may be undefined, as opposed to "property mediaDevices is missing" which you would get if it was not available at all. flow's error messages are vague. Also, thanks.

Comment: Accepted as answer, reluctantly. I did not realize it was actually the answer to my question about navigator.mediaDevices until more recently when I learned that when Flow says "that's undefined" it ACTUALLY means it's an optional property you haven't checked. Or that it's undefined. Or several other things. So it's a correct answer ("this is what you do to fix it") but it's not a good answer ("this is why you're getting an error"); "learning by example" in this case doesn't work because Flow's error messages are vague as hell.